# How do I get the sum of individual lists within a larger list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sum

So I know how to get the sum of a single list so say,

> > a=[1,2,3,4]
> >
> > sum(a)
> >
> > 10

How would I go about trying to sum lists in a list of lists? So, from:

> > [[1,2],[2,3],[3,42]] to
> >
> > [3,5,45]?

Comment: `[sum(lst) for lst in [[1,2],[2,3],[3,42]] ]`

Comment: `print(list(map(sum, data)))` ?

Answer (score 2):

**Code:**

```
l = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,42]]
print([sum(i) for i in l])
```

**Output:**

```
[3, 5, 45]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `sum()` in list comprehension for other lists

```
In [12]: a = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,42]]                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

In [13]: [sum(i) for i in a]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[13]: [3, 5, 45]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
intial_list = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,42]]
res = list(map(sum, intial_list))
print(res)
```

output

```
 [3,5,45]
```

Comment: You don't need lambda here.

Comment: `lambda` is redundant here and just slows thing down

Comment: @OlvinRoght removed lambda , new one is faster than list comprehension

Comment: @prashantrana, yes map is a bit faster then list comprehension on bigger data, just less obvious.

Comment: Your *text* still states that you're using lambda, which you're not!